# wiringPiSetup() hangs system

Tags: wiringpi

My Pi user is a member of the group "gpio". I have a C++ programm calling "wiringPiSetup()".
Whenever I forget to use sudo, my Pi is not reachable anymore and I have to do a power cycle.
I know that I can either use wiringPiSetupSys() or remove my user from gpio.

But no program called from user space should ever be able to hang the system. Why does that happen and how can I prevent it?

Comment: Stop doing what you are doing.

Comment: The documentation quite clearly states that the function needs root privileges. You could uses `suid`

Comment: @Milliways: That's fine, I don't expect it to work. But it should not be possible for a normal user to hang up the entire system